# Laravel 5: organised models in subdirectory not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I am trying to organise my app a bit better by putting models and controllers in subdirectories. I thought it didn't matter if they were in subdirectories as long as the namespace is correct, but now that I've moved them I'm getting a *class not found* error.

I have tried running `composer dumpautoload` several times, but it's still not working.

Here is my directory structure:

- App
- Models

  - Managers

    - EntryStructure.php
    - FieldManager.php
- Controllers

  - EntryControllers.php

Since I have made the new directory *Managers* and moved those two models in there, When I reference the `FieldManager` class from EntryStructure, I get the not found error.

Code in EntryStructure.php:

```
namespace Pascall\ICMS\Models;

use Pascall\ICMS\Models\FieldManager;

class EntryStructure
    {
     function index(){
       new FieldManager(); // class not found
     }
    }
```

Code in FieldManager.php:

```
namespace Pascall\ICMS\Models;

class FieldManager {
  //      
}
```

Why is it not finding the `FieldManager` class when it is explicitly referenced in the `use` statement and they share the same namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Your use should be
 `use Pascall\ICMS\Models\Managers\FieldManager;`
instead
`use Pascall\ICMS\Models\FieldManager;`

Answer (score 0):

If your Models directory follow the PSR-4 specifications, the namespace in both of your classes should follow the class file path, so it should be:

```
namespace Pascall\ICMS\Models\Managers;
```

Then, in `EntryStructure` class you should use:

```
use Pascall\ICMS\Models\Managers\FieldManager;
```